# jQuery - Extraer los últimos 3 caracteres de un texto

Tags: jquery

Tengo el siguiente texto: "Hola mundo", y quisiera extraer los 3 últimos es decir que quedase: "Hola mu". ¿Qué fallo tengo?

**Código**:

```
    $("#quitar_3caracteres").click(function() {
    //Obtenemos primero el texto completo para analizarlo.
    var texto = $(".quintoparrafo").text(); 
    console.log(texto);
    console.log(texto.length); //296
    var texto_nuevo = texto.substr(0,texto.length-3);
    console.log(texto_nuevo);
    console.log(texto_nuevo.length); //293
    $(".quintoparrafo").text(texto_nuevo); 
});
```

¿Por qué me varia la longitud de 296 a 296 si el texto sigue siendo el mismo palabra a palabra, letra a letra, espacio a espacio...?

He escrito en mi código (actualizado) console.log para verlo más claro pero no hace nada, me quite 3 caracteres en la longitud total pero el texto sigue siendo el mismo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que obtener primero el texto de **.tercerparrafo** y luego cambiar los limites del substr que tendría que ser 0 y length - 3;

Por ejemplo:

```
$("#quitar_3caracteres").click(function() {
   var str = $(".tercerparrafo").text(); 
   alert(str.substr(0, str.length-3));
});
```

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta para que lo veas más claro.

Comment: Acabo de probar que con "val" sí me lo transforma. $(".septimoparrafo").html(texto_nuevo);

Comment: ¿Entonces te funciono?.

Comment: Si, duda resuelta.